# How to use multiple ng-model in one function?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, indexeddb

**Hi everyone I'm creating an database using indexed db in Angular js. My task is to save the data into database and my question is can we use multiple ng-model in one function ? Let me show you my code to make it clear.**

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.13" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.13" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div data-ng-app="indexDBSample" data-ng-controller="TodoController as vm">
      <table>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="todo in vm.todos">
          <td>{{todo.text}}</td>
          <td>[<a href="#" data-ng-click="vm.deleteTodo(todo.id)">X</a>]</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br />
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="vm.todoText" name="todo" placeholder="textbox1" style="width: 200px;" />
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="vm.todoText1" name="todo" placeholder="textbox2" style="width: 200px;" />
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="vm.todoText2" name="todo" placeholder="textbox3" style="width: 200px;" />
      <input type="button" value="Add" data-ng-click="vm.addTodo()" />
      <input type="button" value="Refresh" data-ng-click="vm.refreshList()" />
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

*script.js*

```
var app = angular.module('indexDBSample', []);

app.factory('indexedDBDataSvc', function($window, $q){
  var indexedDB = $window.indexedDB;
  var db=null;
  var lastIndex=0;

  var open = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var version = 1;
    var request = indexedDB.open("todoData", version);

    request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
      db = e.target.result;

      e.target.transaction.onerror = indexedDB.onerror;

      if(db.objectStoreNames.contains("todo")) {
        db.deleteObjectStore("todo");
      }

      var store = db.createObjectStore("todo",
        {keyPath: "id"});
    };

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
      db = e.target.result;
      deferred.resolve();
    };

    request.onerror = function(){
      deferred.reject();
    };

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  var getTodos = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if(db === null){
      deferred.reject("IndexDB is not opened yet!");
    }
    else{
      var trans = db.transaction(["todo"], "readwrite");
      var store = trans.objectStore("todo");
      var todos = [];

      // Get everything in the store;
      var keyRange = IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(0);
      var cursorRequest = store.openCursor(keyRange);

      cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
        var result = e.target.result;
        if(result === null || result === undefined)
        {
          deferred.resolve(todos);
        }
        else{
          todos.push(result.value);
          if(result.value.id > lastIndex){
            lastIndex=result.value.id;
          }
          result.continue();
        }
      };

      cursorRequest.onerror = function(e){
        console.log(e.value);
        deferred.reject("Something went wrong!!!");
      };
    }

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  var deleteTodo = function(id){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if(db === null){
      deferred.reject("IndexDB is not opened yet!");
    }
    else{
      var trans = db.transaction(["todo"], "readwrite");
      var store = trans.objectStore("todo");

      var request = store.delete(id);

      request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        deferred.resolve();
      };

      request.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log(e.value);
        deferred.reject("Todo item couldn't be deleted");
      };
    }

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  var addTodo = function(todoText){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if(db === null){
      deferred.reject("IndexDB is not opened yet!");
    }
    else{
      var trans = db.transaction(["todo"], "readwrite");
      var store = trans.objectStore("todo");
      lastIndex++;
      var request = store.put({
        "id": lastIndex,
        "text": todoText
      });

      request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        deferred.resolve();
      };

      request.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log(e.value);
        deferred.reject("Todo item couldn't be added!");
      };
    }
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  return {
    open: open,
    getTodos: getTodos,
    addTodo: addTodo,
    deleteTodo: deleteTodo
  };

});

app.controller('TodoController', function($window, indexedDBDataSvc){
  var vm = this;
  vm.todos=[];

  vm.refreshList = function(){
    indexedDBDataSvc.getTodos().then(function(data){
      vm.todos=data;
    }, function(err){
      $window.alert(err);
    });
  };

  vm.addTodo = function(){
    indexedDBDataSvc.addTodo(vm.todoText).then(function(){
      vm.refreshList();
      vm.todo="";

    }
    , function(err){
      $window.alert(err);
    });
  };



  vm.deleteTodo = function(id){
    indexedDBDataSvc.deleteTodo(id).then(function(){
      vm.refreshList();
    }, function(err){
      $window.alert(err);
    });
  };

  function init(){
    indexedDBDataSvc.open().then(function(){
      vm.refreshList();
    });
  }

  init();
});
```

I have used three ng-model with three different input field but what i need is to use all the three ng-model in one function i.e in

```
    vm.addTodo = function(){
    indexedDBDataSvc.addTodo(vm.todoText).then(function(){
      vm.refreshList();
      vm.todo="";

    }
    , function(err){
      $window.alert(err);
    });
  };
```

to get three different output.Please help me with this because i'm new to angular.js

And here is my plunker :http://plnkr.co/edit/3yM2j9Dgv5FzEP2L9pYH?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the input in the form as:

```
<form name="my_form">
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="vm.todoText" name="todo" placeholder="textbox1" style="width: 200px;" />
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="vm.todoText1" name="todo" placeholder="textbox2" style="width: 200px;" />
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="vm.todoText2" name="todo" placeholder="textbox3" style="width: 200px;" />
       <button type="button" value="Add" data-ng-Click="vm.addTodo(vm)">Add</button>
       <button type="button" value="Refresh" data-ng-Click="vm.refreshList()">Refresh</button>
      </form>
```

In the app.js, in your function, you get all your data from data-ng-model.

```
vm.addTodo = function(vm){
    alert(angular.toJson(vm));
   console.log(angular.toJson(vm.todoText));//check the value in console
   console.log(angular.toJson(vm.todoText1));
   console.log(angular.toJson(vm.todoText2));//you can use the value as vm.todoText,vm.todoText1 and so on.
    indexedDBDataSvc.addTodo(vm.todoText).then(function(){
      vm.refreshList();
      vm.todo="";

    }
    , function(err){
      $window.alert(err);
    });
  };
```

The rest of the logic depends upon whatever you do with the data.

Updates: As per your need of comment.Check your addition of data using your refresh button.Passing the vm as in the original code, created conflict in the controller section so i changed the ng-model to form so that i could get the exact model value.

```
<form name="my_form">
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="form.todoText" name="todo" placeholder="textbox1" style="width: 200px;" />
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="form.todoText1" name="todo" placeholder="textbox2" style="width: 200px;" />
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="form.todoText2" name="todo" placeholder="textbox3" style="width: 200px;" />
       <button type="button" value="Add" data-ng-Click="vm.addTodo(form)">Add</button>
       <button type="button" value="Refresh" data-ng-Click="vm.refreshList()">Refresh</button>
      </form>
```

app.js

```
 vm.addTodo = function(vm){
    angular.forEach(vm,function(key,value){
    indexedDBDataSvc.addTodo(key).then(function(){
      $window.location.reload();
      vm.todo="";

    }
    , function(err){
      $window.alert(err);
    });
    });
  };
```

Checkout this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/xyR2W1GpylMXofIKi1BR?p=preview

Comment: Hi @Alex rumba I'm happy with your solution just show me how to  use vm.todoText , vm.todoText1 , vm.todoText2 inside indexedDBDataSvc.addTodo(vm.todoText).then(function(){
      vm.refreshList();
      vm.todo="";

    }   part .

Comment: check the updates in the answer if that helps you, do upvote and mark it correct.

Comment: The solution is correct but i need the output as same as what i type in the text box. please help me with that.

Comment: I edited the plunker as well. Use the key instead of value to push. as simple as that. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103577/discussion-between-alex-rumba-and-anil-chean).